# RAID50 slow write speed

Tags: windows, raid, storage, supermicro

**Initial Configuration:**

RAID:

- Disk Drives: 6 HDD TOSHIBA MBF2600RC (600 Gb, 16 Mb, 10025 RPM, SAS,
  600 Mb/s)
- 2 Spans
- Motherboard: SuperMicro X8DTU-6F+/6TF
- RAID Controller: SuperMicro SMC2108
- Virtual Group: RAID50
- Polices:

  - Access: RW
  - Read: Normal
  - Disk Cache: Enable
  - I/O: Cached
  - Disable BGI: NO
  - Default Write: Write Through

Used Operation System: Windows Server 2016

**Result:**

CrystalDiskMark Metrics:

```
Read [MB/s]: 221.5

Write [MB/s]: 38.30
```

Ubuntu Live CD Metrics:

```
Read [MB/s]: 270.1

Write [MB/s]: 49.5
```

**Question:**

What can I attempt to increase Write Speed?

Should I reconfigure RAID50 settings, or configure different type of RAID?

Comment: Is this a new array? What OS? One solution would be to not use "_hardware_" RAID... (which has other benefits too)

Comment: ["_Write Through_" vs "_Write Back_" caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)#Writing_policies) will likely affect this significantly, though make sure you have NV cache (or backup power) if you use Write Back.

Comment: So... 6 disks = 2 spans of 3 disks each?  Try deleting and recreating the RAID.  Use a live CD to test the I/O.  You could always try a different RAID type to test.  Doing three mirror sets and then I/O test against each might indicate if a drive is the culprit.  You could also look to the RAID controller.  Make sure you're on the most updated firmware for it from the vendor.

Comment: Thanks for response. I've updated my question to clarify your notes

Comment: @Attie, could you please tell what kind of 'Default Write' should I use to increase the speed? In accordance with the article you've sent Write-back is the faster case. Is it right?

Comment: Write Back will give you a higher write speed... until your cache fills up... but before enabling it you _must_ make sure that you have NVRAM or suitable backup power (e.g: battery / super cap).

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them

Answer (score 0):

Changing Default Write policy to 'WRITE ALWAYS BACK' has aligned rate of speed:

> Read [MB/s]: 222.6
>
> Write [MB/s]: 208.8

So it's a good practice to consider this option for write intensive tasks.

Comment: Write-back cache substantially increases the risk of data loss in some use cases, as it does not guarantee that the data is written to permanent media (only to the cache) -- failure without a battery-backed cache is potentially damaging.